# Two lines above & below arrow

Tags: arrows

क्रोष्टान् + स् $\xrightarrow[\stackrel{\normalsize\text{}}{\shortstack[c]{{\textcolor{blue}{\text{\scriptsize{\nameref{8.2.7}}}}}\   \textcolor{blue}{\text{\scriptsize{नकार gets लोप}}}}}]{\stackrel{\normalsize\text{}}{\shortstack[c]{{\textcolor{black}{\text{\scriptsize{\nameref{6.1.68}}}}}\ \text{\scriptsize{सकार gets लोप \&}}}}}$
[image]

I am not sure if this is the best way to work with. It worked so I adopted it. But now my document is getting really big and I am worried if it would cause any sort of problems later.

Also can I create a command where I can use text to the left and right of the arrow and all four lines above & below the arrow as arguments. So far I was getting by with copy paste and changing the text as needed. Just to give an idea in my 200 page document this thing came so far around 300 times.

thanks for your comments

PS: The font is unicode Devanagari(Sanskrit2003)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Simply put, is this the best way to create this or if there is any simple and more effective way to achieve the same. Also if I can add this to custom command so that the two line above and below can be inserted as command arguments. Because editing becomes hard because of so much code around it.  I am not sure if I made myself any clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just putting the code that you gave inside a `\newcommand`. Is it what was needed?

```
\newcommand{\TwoSidedTextArrow}[6]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \xrightarrow[%
    \stackrel{\normalsize\text{}}{%
      \shortstack[c]{%
        {\textcolor{blue}{\text{\scriptsize{\nameref{#1}}}}}\ %
        \textcolor{blue}{\text{\scriptsize{#2 gets #3}}}%
      }}]{%
    \stackrel{\normalsize\text{}}{%
      \shortstack[c]{%
        {\textcolor{black}{\text{\scriptsize{\nameref{#4}}}}}\ %
        \text{\scriptsize{#5 gets #6 \&}}}%
    }}%
  }%
}
```

Your example then becomes

```
क्रोष्टान् + स् \TwoSidedTextArrow{8.2.7}{नकार}{लोप}{6.1.68}{सकार}{लोप}
```

Comment: awesome, thats exactly what I need, sorry if I could not be more specific in explaining the question.

Comment: @Aku: Out of curiosity, is `\nameref` producing all this text which appears in the line with 8.2.7?

Comment: yes it is producing, I created a file where all the text is saved as sections and associated a label with it. I call using nameref{} function and it nicely recalls the text that I saved in a separate file. I am not sure if thats the best way to do. the reason I did is because I have around 4300 such labels and I do not want to print them in the pdf file, using \includeonly I exclude that text file in the pdf output and wherever I need I call the desired text using \nameref. I am a newbie ,so not sure how to do I picked whatever worked now learning through this site how to be effective